# Can I find an example of Java XML configuration without XSD schema or XPATH?

Tags: java, xml, configuration

I need to create an XML configuration file as simple as possible.  As I understand using jaxb requires creating a schema file. Using XPathAPI does not allow direct conversion XML to a Java bean – one needs to use XPATH.  The same is with Apache commons Configuration.

Is it possible to avoid using schema or XPath, maybe with XMLEncoder?

Comment: It's not not true that JAXB needs a schema. You can create Java-Classes with proper annotations and use them to read/write your XML file.

Comment: Thank you, I used previously JAXB only with a schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a tool like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), which can serialize and deserialize arbitrary object graphs into XML.  It will often make a pretty good guess at what element names to use, but you can configure the mapping using annotations or by making method calls on the `XStream` object before marshalling/unmarshalling.